# Preventing a Session which is a list of other session values from rewriting

Tags: asp.net, session

In an ASP.Net web form application I consider a session:

```
((List<clsSharedVariables>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ListVariables"])
```

By each click on menu items, I redirect the user to a new tab and before redirecting I save current sessions in this list:

```
 clsSharedVariables currentSession = new clsSharedVariables();
        currentSession = (clsSharedVariables)HttpContext.Current.Session["SharedVariables"];
        var ListSharedVariables = ((List<clsSharedVariables>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ListVariables"]);

        var currentTabId = ListSharedVariables.Count + 1;
        currentSession.CurrentTabId = currentTabId;
        if (!ListSharedVariables.Contains(currentSession))
        {
            ListSharedVariables.Add(currentSession);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ListVariables"] = ListSharedVariables;
        }
```

the problem is that when I click on each item in the menu, all of items in the ListVariables update to the last session value. I can't understand how and why; Because the list is standalone and the outer values can not change the values in the list. For example, in the code above when I set :

```
currentSession.CurrentTabId = currentTabId;
```

the currentTabId of the old items in the HttpContext.Current.Session["ListVariables"] change to this new value and this is a very big bug I think.

Can you understand where is the problem? what wrong link there is between this values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you only have references to one instance of the `clsSharedVariables`-class in your list `List<clsSharedVariables>`.
When you change the value of one property of that instance, the changes is there for all references too, because the are just pointing to the instance.

Here you get your instance from the session:
`currentSession = (clsSharedVariables)HttpContext.Current.Session["SharedVariables"];`

And so you just add a reference to the list with
`ListSharedVariables.Add(currentSession);`

To avoid this, you could use a struct instead of a class for your `clsSharedVariables` - because struct is a value type.

For more info about the difference of value and reference types look e.g. [at this article](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html)